# Multiple OR conditions in SAS if...then...statement

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am trying to construct two new variables named house_ins and food_ins. These variables are based on whether the participant has met certain conditions. (as shown in below codes) In this case, if any question criteria have been met, then I can construct it as food or house insecurity.  However, it isn't the correct result. Wondering if I have made mistakes somewhere. Thanks

```
if worry_food_t0 OR food_didnt_last_t0 in (-99,-88,.) then food_ins=.;
else if worry_food_t0 OR food_didnt_last_t0 in (1,2) then food_ins=1;
else if worry_food_t0=3 OR food_didnt_last_t0=3 then food_ins=0;
if (housed_where_t0 or living_where_t0 or rent_mortgage_t0 or living_with_others_t0) 
in (-99,-88,-77,.) then house_ins=.;
else if (housed_where_t0=1 OR living_where_t0 in (3,4) OR rent_mortgage_t0=0 OR 
living_with_others_t0=0) then house_ins=0;
else if (housed_where_t0 in (2,3,4,5,6) OR living_where_t0 in (1,2) OR 
rent_mortgage_t0=1 OR living_with_others_t0=1) then house_ins=1;
```

Comment: Why are you treating WORRY_FOOD_T0 as a boolean value but treating FOOD_DIDNT_LAST_T0 as a categorical value?

Comment: Based on the codebook, they are both categorical variables.

Comment: Then you have to test each one separately.  If you write VAR1 OR ... then you are saying treat the value of VAR1 as if it is TRUE or FALSE.  SAS will treat 0 or missing as FALSE and any other value as TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't speak English.

`worry_food_t0 OR food_didnt_last_t0 in (-99,-88,.)` is not the same as `worry_food_t0 in (-99,-88,.) OR food_didnt_last_t0 in (-99,-88,.)` for them.

In SAS in boolean operation `worry_food_t0 OR food_didnt_last_t0` evaluates

- to `1`, meaning True, if either of them is a non zero number
- to `0`, meaning False, in all other cases

Only then it is checked if the result is in `(-99,-88,.)`

You probably mean

```
if worry_food_t0 in (-99,-88,.)
OR food_didnt_last_t0 in (-99,-88,.) then food_ins=.;
else 
if worry_food_t0 in (1,2)
OR food_didnt_last_t0 in (1,2) then food_ins=1;
else 
if worry_food_t0=3 in=3
OR food_didnt_last_t0=3 then food_ins=0;

if housed_where_t0 in (-99,-88,-77,.)
or living_where_t0 in (-99,-88,-77,.)
or rent_mortgage_t0 in (-99,-88,-77,.)
or living_with_others_t0 in (-99,-88,-77,.) then house_ins=.;
else 
if housed_where_t0=1 
OR living_where_t0 in (3,4) 
OR rent_mortgage_t0=0 
OR living_with_others_t0=0) then house_ins=0;
else 
if housed_where_t0 in (2,3,4,5,6) 
OR living_where_t0 in (1,2) 
OR rent_mortgage_t0=1 
OR living_with_others_t0=1 then house_ins=1;
```

Comment: Boolean expression never evaluate to missing in SAS.  SAS only does BINARY logic.

Comment: You are right. I was testing it while you gave this comment. See my edits.